# How to create full width background elements?

Tags: html, css

My page size is `960px`. However I want two backgrounds on the top of my page (for the headers) that will use `100%`.

A full width black background, and bellow it a full width gray background.

[I've tried the following <sup>jsFiddle</sup>](http://jsfiddle.net/jEYbP/)

```
<header id="bg1"></header>
<header id="bg2"></header>

<section id="page">
    <header id="page-header">
        <div>
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </nav>
            <h2>SiteLogo</h2>
        </div>
    </header>
</section>
```

`bg1` should be a black background and `bg2` a gray one.

```
#bg1 {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: -60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lime;
}
#bg2 {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid cyan;
}

#page-header {height: 60px;}
#page{margin:0 auto;width: 360px;} /* 960px */

body {color: #fff}
nav { float: right; }
nav a { color: #fff; }
```

I actually check how `Stack Overflow` did it, and it seems I am doing right, but it only works for a single element. When I try to use a second element it goes above the first.

So my question is, how can I fix it so I will have a full-width black background and bellow it a full-width gray background?

Comment: You could also "cheat" by just making one `header`, the black one, and just make the gray one a border at the bottom of the black one, by adding: `border-bottom: 20px solid #ccc` to `#bg1`

Comment: Why the margin-bottoms? Don't they cause the trouble?

Comment: Can you post an image of what you're trying to achieve? Everyone tries to help by guessing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to place the logo + nav bar on the black background? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jEYbP/6/

```
#bg1 {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lime;
}
#bg2 {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid cyan;
}

#page-header {height: 60px;}
#page{margin:-80px auto 0;width: 360px;} /* 960px */

body {color: #fff}
nav { float: right; }
nav a { color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the negative bottom margins from your bg1 and bg2 divs. Doing this pulls the elements below upward.

```
#bg1 {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lime;
}
#bg2 {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid cyan;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jEYbP/2/)**

Comment: what was with that `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` thing which you deleted, edited, and undeleted...?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you'll need to simply pull ( negative top margin ) the container content ( your navigation in this case ) into the gray background that spans the width of the page.

The only element that you'll need to apply the negative top margin to is the last background element, in this case it's `#bg2` -- you can leave `#bg1` without a negative top margin since you're not trying to "pull" content into it.

So, you'll end up with CSS like this ( using your current markup ):

```
#bg1 {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lime;
}
#bg2 {
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: -60px; // This pulls the content below it into this space
    border-bottom: 1px solid cyan;
}
```

Here's a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jEYbP/3/